# How to Export After Effect to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio-3.0, after-effects

I want to export file from After Effect to Android Studio, can someone help me how to run it? for example how to export splash screen to android studio and make it work? I hope someone to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export your animation with [bodymovin](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web) then render it on Android with [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)